# Multiprocessing does not process all files in folder and write to a single file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a folder full of metadata xml files I am parsing them and write the output as single lines to a csv. I am trying to use multiprocessing to speed this up and I have about 13000 files in the folder however I see that as I increase my pool size the program does not process all files. This is my code till now

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import os,subprocess,csv

mfile=r"C:\demo\metadata_parsed.csv"
errorlog=r"C:\demo\errorlog.csv"
with open(mfile,'wb') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=["id_no", "system:time_start", "platform"], delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()
with open(errorlog,'wb') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=["id_no"], delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()
def get_image_paths(folder):
        return(os.path.join(folder,f)
           for f in os.listdir(folder))

def download_item(images):
        infilename=images
        fsp=images.split("_x")[0]
        from xml.dom import minidom #This gets the main xml parse tree
        xmldoc=minidom.parse(infilename)
        ps=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ps:EarthObservationMetaData")[0]
        observation=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ps:EarthObservationResult") [0]
        eopfilename=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("eop:fileName")[0].firstChild.data
        meta=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ps:EarthObservationMetaData")[0]
        acquisition= meta.getElementsByTagName("eop:acquisitionDate")[0].firstChild.data
        date_time = acquisition.split("T")[0]
        pattern = '%Y-%m-%d'
        epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))*1000
        print("epoch time", epoch)
        with open("C:\demo\metadata_parsed.csv",'a') as csvfile:
            writer=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerow([os.path.basename(fsp),epoch,platform])
        csvfile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1=time.time()
    folder=r"F:\demo\metadata"
    images=get_image_paths(folder)
    pool = Pool(20)
    pool.map(download_item,images)
    pool.close() # signal that we won't submit any more tasks to pool
    pool.join() # wait until all processes are done
    print("Pool took:",time.time()-t1)
```

And and all help would be appreciated

Comment: you should check `len(images)` first, then check if they all passed through `download_item` (`fsp` is ok for all files ?)

Comment: I tried looking at len(images) and the count is correct at 13000 files when I run program so no problems there for now I also removed the close csv but the problem persists. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could add a global counter inside `download_item()` to compare with `len(images)`.   You said the problem occurs when you increase the pool, what did you get whit a lower pool value ? BTW, you should move `from xml.dom import minidom` from the running function, you need it only once